# uncaught syntex error: unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript

[attached code and error]\

```
var a = 'hello';
first();

function first() {
  var b = 'hi';
  second();

  function second() {
    var c = 'hey';

    console.log(a + b + c);
  }
}

function third() {
  var d = 'john';
  console.log(c);
}
```

i'm getting issue 'uncaught syntax error: unexpected end of input.
'. How to fix this, have check many time, but getting same issue.

Comment: The code you provided here works fine when I run it.

Comment: there are no errors in your code. I think the error is returning from another code block or file, please check your code from online js editor (copy & paste your code) https://playcode.io/

Answer (score 0):

//Hii Vikas try this

```
var a = 'hello';
var b = '';
var c = '';
var d = '';

function first() {
   b = 'hi';
  second();
}

  function second() {
     c = 'hey';
    console.log(a + b + c);
  }


function third() {
   d = 'john';
  console.log(c);
}

first();
```

Comment: @Utsav: How will this change the result?